# Python Dash Table - How to embed href behind cell value

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

[Dash table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d0aC.png)

Hi,

How can I embed the links into the product name columns so I can remove the link column?
I'd like to access the links by clicking on the product name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put in the question the piece of code that generates the dash table. It will help to get suitable answers

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. I will first drop the `Link` column. Assuming `df` is your data.

```py
df_drop_link = df.drop(columns='Link')

html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in df_drop_link.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(df.iloc[i][col]) if col != 'Product Name' else html.Td(html.A(href=df.iloc[i]['Link'], children=df.iloc[i][col], target='_blank')) for col in df_drop_link.columns 
        ]) for i in range(len(df))]
    )
```

[image]

Comment: How can we in incorporate pagination along with this?